# Angular 14 - How to specify a form control is not undefined

Tags: angular, angular14

**Say I have a form:-**

```
searchForm = new FormGroup({
      SearchBox = new FormControl<string>('', {nonNullable: true});
)}
```

**And I try to do this:-**

```
this.Query = this.searchForm.SearchBox.value;
```

The type of the Query property is a string, I get the error.

> "Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'".

I can use the ! operator to make it work like so.

```
this.Query = this.searchForm.SearchBox.value!;
```

But is this the best way to tell it that the form control won't be undefined? Is there a better way to do this rather than slapping ! everywhere I want to assign the value of a form control to a property in the component?

Answer (score 14):

The type `undefined` is added because if the control is disabled, it’ll not be included in the value object.
Read more on the angular docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formgroup-and-formrecord).

If you want to access the value including disabled controls, and thus bypass possible undefined fields, you can use `searchForm.getRawValue()`